# Intellij IDEA - how to find package usage in a project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am looking at a project's maven pom file with a lot of dependencies and trying to find out if a particular dependency is used or not. Is there a way in Intellij IDEA to find all import statements that import any class from a particular package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm working with IntelliJ IDEA 14 UE.

1. switch to the view "Project"
2. in the tree view, go to the node "External Libraries"
3. search the particular library (=dependency) and open the node
4. select a package within this library
5. in the popup menu of this package, click "Find usages". Alternatively, press Alt+F7 (Windows)

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. It only shows me references to the exact package. I'm looking for usages of any class in that package.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to do it directly in IntelliJ but you can always use the `analyse` goal of the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html).

Here is a [link](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2014/01/analyze-your-maven-project-dependencies.html) to a nice example of the plugin.